RIP Tony Todd (1954 – 2024)
Recently, Tony Todd (December 4, 1954 – November 6, 2024) passed away.
He was well-known in the sci-fi community for the portrayals of Kurn in Start Trek TNG and DS9, Alpha-Hirogen in Star Trek Voyager and, of course, adult Jake Sisko in DS9.
He also had credits for  many other acting and voice-acting roles, far to many to list here, but for example in Hercules, Xena, Smallville, Stargate SG1, the X-files and others.


Wow, I was just looking him up today, trying to remember one of his roles.  Too bad.

Also played the guy who seemed to know what was going in in Final Destination, when the protagonists were trying to cheat Death.

Also, Candyman.

@FuzzyBoots Candyman, Candyman, Candyman, Candyman, Candyman.
